# Django. Не передается результат одной из функций из вьюхи в шаблон

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, парсер

Дано:

```
views.py
```

в котором содержатся 2 функции, парсящие списки. Одна - список бранчей в проекте Gitlab, вторая - тянет список методов:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
import cx_Oracle
import subprocess


def method_list(request):
    settings.configure()
    con = cx_Oracle.connect('USER', 'PaSsWoRd', 'work.rus')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    sql = 'select * from (select distinct class_id from methods order by 1) where rownum <20'
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    parsed_methods_string = str(result).replace('(\'', '').replace('[', '').replace(', ', '').replace(']', '').replace('\',)', '\n')
    parsed_methods = parsed_methods_string.split('\n')[:-1]
    print(parsed_methods)
    return render(request, 'blog/branch_list.html', {'parsed_methods': parsed_methods})


def branch_list(request):
    result = subprocess.run("gitlab project-branch list --project-id 3", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8', shell=True).stdout
    br_list = result.replace('\n\n', '\n').replace('\n\n', '\n').replace('name: ', '').replace(', ', '\n')
    parsed_branches = br_list.split('\n')[:-1]
    print(parsed_branches)
    return render(request, 'blog/branch_list.html', {'parsed_branches': parsed_branches})
```

```
urls.py
```

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from . import models

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.branch_list, name='branch_list'),
    path('', views.method_list, name='method_list')
]
```

И шаблон

```
branch_list.html
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
            <title>Загрузка</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Выберите метод для загрузки</p>
            <p>{{ parsed_methods }}</p>
            <div class="method">
                <select>
                          {% for a in parsed_methods  %}
                    <option>{{ a }}</option>
                          {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
            <p>Выберите бранч для загрузки</p>
            <p>{{ parsed_branches }}</p>
            <div class="branch">
                <select>
                          {% for a in parsed_branches  %}
                    <option>{{ a }}</option>
                          {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Т.е., распарсены оба списка, но в шаблон не передается лист из функции `method_list`

Собственно, не могу понять ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: в url.py 2 функции передаешь?

Comment: @user355827, добавил в описание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в return 1 функции

```
return render(request, 'blog/branch_list.html', {'parsed_branches': parsed_methods})
```

замените на

```
return render(request, 'blog/branch_list.html', {'parsed_methods': parsed_methods})
```

это точно должно помочь

```
 def method_list(request):
    settings.configure()
    con = cx_Oracle.connect('USER', 'PaSsWoRd', 'work.rus')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    sql = 'select * from (select distinct class_id from methods order by 1) where rownum <20'
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    parsed_methods_string = str(result).replace('(\'', '').replace('[', '').replace(', ', '').replace(']', '').replace('\',)', '\n')
    parsed_methods = parsed_methods_string.split('\n')[:-1]
    print(parsed_methods)

    result_brunch = subprocess.run("gitlab project-branch list --project-id 3", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8', shell=True).stdout
    br_list = result_brunch.replace('\n\n', '\n').replace('\n\n', '\n').replace('name: ', '').replace(', ', '\n')
    parsed_branches = br_list.split('\n')[:-1]
    print(parsed_branches)
    return render(request, 'blog/branch_list.html', {'parsed_methods': parsed_methods, 'parsed_branches': parsed_branches})
```

Comment: да, исправил. Так и было изначально. Это уже следы экспериментов. Но результат без изменений

Comment: @ИльяДмитриев попробуй так как обновил, пробовал в своем проекте небольшом передавать 2 функции на 1 шаблон чет тоже не работало, пришлось объединить. Наверное так сделать нельзя, ну или использовать классы надо. Сам недавно начал учить django могу и ошибаться

Comment: Спасибо! С некоторыми фиксами именно то что надо! Было у меня подозрение что надо объединить функции, но так и не сделал. Не уверен был что в одном render() можно отправить 2 реквеста сразу

Comment: @ИльяДмитриев возможно это не идеальный вариант но вполне рабочий)

Comment: в моем случае его более чем достаточно))